# list comprehension error and algorithm

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

There is a couple questions about the list comprehension in python. The first is I do not know why there is error in the code below:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,9,4,5,0,0,2,3,0,9,6]
test = [x++ for x in alist if x != 0]
File "<stdin>", line 1
test = [x++ for x in list1 if x != 0]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another question is I want to write a list comprehension to count non-zero element. Use `alist` as an example, I want to return a list called `count` containing 1 or 0: 1 if the element in `alist` is not zero and zero is the element in `alist` is zero. So the result should be:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,9,4,5,0,0,2,3,0,9,6] 
count = [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you expect `x++` to do? Python has no `++` operator. List comprehensions create a new list, so perhaps you wanted `[x + 1 for x in alist if x != 0]`?

Comment: Please stick to *one* question per post. Split out your two questions into separate posts.

Comment: @vaultah Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question, please try the followed

```
    count=[1 if x>0 else 0 for x in alist]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a `++` operator (or equivalent increment or decrement operators) because Python integer objects (and float objects) are *immutable*.

So you need to do

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,9,9,4,5,0,0,2,3,0,9,6]
test = [x+1 for x in alist if x != 0]
print(test)
```

**output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 10, 5, 6, 3, 4, 10, 7]
```